# How do I use data from two sql tables in sqlalchemy

Tags: sql, python-3.x, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

This is my code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUQCt.png)

I have two tables on my database. One is reviews and the other is books. I want to take `bookid` from books and insert it into the reviews table when a user enters the values. I have made it a foreign key but unable to understand how to put it in a query

Comment: Hi, please do not post screenshots of code, instead add the code here. It makes life easier for those who want to use your code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but do you know how to solve it

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear to me. Are you asking how you could store a new review by associating it to the book?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not very clear, like what is books.isbn is not defined anywhere.

On the basis of our requirement, sqlalchemy will be very useful, you can try below snippet, with slight modification to your code.

```
book = session.query(Book).filter_by(name='book1').first()
review = Review(review='very good', rating='5', book_id=book.id)
session.add(review)
session.commit()
```

1. Sqlalchemy query method is used to generate sql select query.
2. Sqlalchemy filter method is used to filter out records based on condition in filter function.
3. Sqlalchemy add method is used to insert data into the table. Like in this example, we have to add to declare Review class that has been mapped to review table. We have to declare an object of this class and persistently add it to the table by add() method of session object.